# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: My take: Site is stable, but hardly growing. At that point where it tends to be the same group of regulars involved with many (but not all) questions. Quality varies widely: lackluster questions get lackluster answers, detailed expert questions tend to get better information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Help with heat issue with pontiac vibe (toyota matrix)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/help-with-heat-issue-with-pontiac-vibe-toyota-matrix)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Battery voltage slightly low. Especially when the car's been sitting for a while](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8464/battery-voltage-slightly-low-especially-when-the-cars-been-sitting-for-a-while)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [key wont turn inside](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8585/key-wont-turn-inside)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [RPM fluctuation when maintaining speed in high gear](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/rpm-fluctuation-when-maintaining-speed-in-high-gear)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Writing CAN Messages](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/writing-can-messages)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much protection do grill guards give?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/how-much-protection-do-grill-guards-give)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [steering angle sensor in indian cars](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/steering-angle-sensor-in-indian-cars)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [89 jeep cherokee will run but when i turn it off and try to restart it the battery is dead](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8515/89-jeep-cherokee-will-run-but-when-i-turn-it-off-and-try-to-restart-it-the-batte)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What items are in the cooling system loop?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/what-items-are-in-the-cooling-system-loop)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Methods of diagnosing a non-starting Fiat Uno](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/methods-of-diagnosing-a-non-starting-fiat-uno)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Answer (score 1):

Noticing the scores for the final results, it looks like only four people contributed on (most of) the questions. I also notice, Friday nights are pretty slow in here. I would suspect that's because those with car problems are not worried about it until Saturday morning. Just a couple of observations.